# Loop Through First Row and Column and paste values to another Sheet with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy each cell in the first Row and paste it cell A1 in sheet number 2. And then paste the number back in sheet1 cell B2. I want to repeat this for all values in first column and first row. I have attached a sample excel file showing what results i should get.

I have written a code which does not work.

```
Sub check()
    Dim i, j As Long
    Dim rng1, rng2 As Range

    For i = 1 To 3
        For j = 1 To 3        
            Set rng1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:K1")
            Set rng2 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10")

            For Each Cell In rng1      
                Cell.Value.Copy
                Sheets("2").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues    
                Sheets("2").Range("A3").Copy
                Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i + 1, j + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            Next Cell
        Next j
    Next i
```

[image]

Comment: Note that `Dim i, j As Long` only declares `j As Long` but `i As Variant` you need to specify a type for  **every** variable in VBA. `Dim i As Long, j As Long`. Same for `Dim rng1, rng2 As Range`. • Please tell what is in sheet 2 cell B2 (Formula) and what your actual goal is. I ask this because I think you are up the wrong tree with this approach.

Comment: @Peh Formula is A1*B1*3

Comment: So why don't you just fill a formula in your Sheet1? That would be the correct way to go.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am doing this as a basis for another exercise that would have a similar scenario. Its so important for me to get this Macro right.